# Sending Tweet with video (Error creating status.)

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I am trying to send a tweet with video but getting following error in the "await twitterCtx.TweetWithMediaAsync" line

> Error creating status.

```
        if (Request.Params["VideoId"] != "")
        {
            AspNetAuthorizer auth = (AspNetAuthorizer)Session["TW"];

            var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

            string status = "Testing TweetWithMedia #Linq2Twitter £ " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            const bool PossiblySensitive = false;
            const decimal Latitude = TwitterContext.NoCoordinate;
            const decimal Longitude = TwitterContext.NoCoordinate;
            const bool DisplayCoordinates = false;
            const string PlaceID = null;
            string ReplaceThisWithYourImageLocation = @"c:\foo\foo\" + Request.Params["VideoId"] + ".mp4";

            byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ReplaceThisWithYourImageLocation);

            Status tweet = await twitterCtx.TweetWithMediaAsync(
                status, PossiblySensitive, Latitude, Longitude,
                PlaceID, DisplayCoordinates, imageBytes);

        }
```

video size ~3MB

Comment: Does it work without video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API only supports uploading images. Also, *TweetWithMediaAsync* (=Twitter API *statuses\update_with_media* endpoint) is deprecated and replaced with *UploadMediaAsync* (=Twitter API *media\upload* endpoint).

You can download [LINQ to Twitter source code](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#New/Demos/Linq2TwitterDemos_Console/StatusDemos.cs) for a demo and read my blog post, [Uploading Multiple Images in Parallel with Async and LINQ to Twitter](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2014/10/21/uploading-multiple-images-in-parallel-with-async-and-linq-to.aspx), for more info.

**Update**

Please see @Jagadeesh Govindaraj answer as Video uploads are a new capability that is now available.

Comment: so there is no way I upload videos programmatically?

Comment: @Mert No, there never has been.

Answer (score 1):

Is now posible to upload Videos in Twitter

```
priavte async Task UploadVideoAsync(TwitterContext twitterCtx)
{
                var additionalOwners = new List<ulong> { 3265644348, 15411837 };
                string status =
                    "Testing video upload tweet #Linq2Twitter £ " +
                    DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var media = await twitterCtx.UploadMediaAsync(
                    File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\images\SampleVideo.mp4"), "video/mp4");

                Status tweet = await twitterCtx.TweetAsync(status, new ulong[] { media.MediaID });

                if (tweet != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Tweet sent: " + tweet.Text);
}
```

**Note :**Code from orginal Samples in [LinqtoTwitter](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki/Uploading-And-Tweeting-Media)

Answer (score 0):

It is supporting now.
But i can not success with UploadMediaAsync :) The second param is not mime type, it is cancellation token, so twitter can not recognize my mp4 file ;)